# Android - Sqlite search using LIKE and UPPER on International characters

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts, android-cursor

I am currently trying to run a search on the contacts database and where a value I pass in matches the display name in the contacts I want to return a cursor with the number of contacts that match.

Currently this works OK except for international characters, here is how my code currently looks with constraint being a CharSequence taken from an EditText:

```
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        };

String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

        String SELECTION = "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ")" 
            + " LIKE UPPER('%" + constraint+ "%') " + "and " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " IS NOT NULL"
         + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                    PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, sortOrder);

    return cur; 
}
```

As I said this works fine as I want the search to be case insensitive so the user doesn't have to type the exact name, with a normal English name this works fine however once international characters are introduced the search becomes case sensitive.

I have done some research that suggests sqlite requires an ICU add on to make this work that is missing from Android. Or to use a collate when inserting into the database. However since I only read from the contacts content provider this is not an option for me.

Does anyone know of a way to get the search in the code above to work with International characters while being case insensitive?

Comment: Could you please share the solution that worked for you